# Run a management task after all South migrations are done

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south, database-migration

I was wondering if it's possible to run a management task (which basically pre-populates the DB with some data from JSON) after all the have migrations finished running. A post-migrate step, if you will.

The closest I could find was (a very helpful) `post_migrate` signal, which I hooked in like so:

```
@receiver(post_migrate)
def loadInitialData(app, verbosity, interactive, db, **kwargs):
    management.call_command('loadInitialData')
```

However it gets called after *every* single migration is ran. I understand this is the intended behaviour, but is it possible to only execute after *all* migration have finished running?

A hacky method I thought of is just going through all the files in the `/migrations` directory and ripping out the numbers, and just finding max and then comparing that in `ran_migration` signal.

Is there anything better? Sorry if it's an obvious question, I'm quite new to South.

Comment: You are looking for a feature that django provides called fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files

Comment: South also has data migrations: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#datamigration

Comment: I initially thought about using fixtures, but could find any information about the order of loading. I'd like them to be loaded after all migrations were done, both in normal migrate and in test environment (i.e. run by `migrate`). Problem with data migrations is they are still numbered, so I'm not sure how to express the concept of post-migrate data loading.

Comment: Also, @karthikr, fixtures don't seem to be loaded after the migrations.